# complex integral around contour

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm looking for some advice on talking this simple contour integration question. I am unsure of which theorem I should apply.

Let $C$ be the circle centred at the origin and with radius 2 and let

$$
f(z)=  \frac {z^2}{z^2+2z+2}
$$

Find the integral of $f(z)$ around the contour C

Comment: You may want to check out [residual theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem)

Comment: Yes I am famaliar with the theorem however am unsure how to find the poles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by factoring the denominator and doing a partial fraction decomposition, to get
$$
f(z) = 1 - \frac1{z+1+i}-\frac1{z+1-i}
$$
So there are two simple poles, each with strength $-1$, located at $-1-i$ and $-1+i$. These locations are within the contour $C$ (they are $\sqrt{2}<2$ from the origin.

So if the contour used goes counterclockwise around $C$, the integral will be
$$
(2\pi i) ([-1]+[-1]) = -4\pi i
$$
Of course if the contour were meant to go in the clockwise direction the answer would be $+4\pi i$.

Comment: How do you arrive at the partial fractions and then see that the poles are as you've stated? I understand when a pole occurs I'm just unsure how you've arrived at it

Comment: @juper: I think there's a typo here. $\frac{1}{2+1-i}$ should be $\frac{1}{z+1-i}$, I think.

Comment: yes that makes more sense. thank to you both!